# Email Validation in Annotation in C# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, annotations

Guys,

I have implemented email annotation in MVC which is like below and this working fine.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64})$", ErrorMessage = " Please input a valid email address")]
```

But I have a scenario where I want to treat all the text ***@domain.com** as email.

What I need to change so both validations can work same time.

Comment: Can you give an example of that text?

Comment: *@domain.com

where if anything comes before @ does not matter, all i have to check the domain

Comment: if this is only about domain check then use `^.*@domain\.com$` https://dotnetfiddle.net/nDH0rS